# What do we call a continuous function that induces a homeomorphism onto its image?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I know that an order-homomorphism that induces an isomorphism onto its image is called an *order-embedding*. So, I was expecting that a continuous function that induces an homeomorphism onto its image would be called a 'continuous embedding.' But, nothing really came up when I googled this phrase.

What's the standard terminology?

Comment: I've seen homeomorphic embedding for topological spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks I corrected the question.

Comment: Isn't this just a topological embedding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of general topology such a map is called simply an [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology). You could call it a *topological embedding* if you wanted to make the domain of discourse absolutely clear, and I’m pretty sure that I’ve also seen *homeomorphic embedding*.